# Query in Open edX

Tags: uploading, edx, openedx

Hey currently I'm working on **open edX** and I am having some sort of problem in uploading a content like (&,<,>) mathematical symbols in Multiple Choice. Is there any sort of solution for this.

Comment: Yes, there is. Maybe you want do describe the problems in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add mathematical problems/equations you can use MathJax 
https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/open-edx-building-and-running-a-course/en/latest/exercises_tools/mathjax.html

Or

You can use HTML values/codes for those ASCII characters, click "advanced editor" and add.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but answering in case it helps someone stuck with the same issue.

Open Edx Problem configuration (for example, Multiple Choice, Checkboxes etc.) do not allow certain mathematical symbols which conflict with HTML - for example, <, > etc. You can use the equivalent HTML tags for these (`&lt;` for < and `&gt;` for >) and they will display correctly.